# How to generate random `POINTS` within a POSTGIS Polygon?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, postgis, geoserver

I have a postgresql table and trying to insert randomized geo locations within the US to the column `geo_location`. However, my LAT/LONG and are a little off and some points are showing in the oceans. So I went to get the exact polygon of the US and need the points to only show up when they are WITHIN that polygon. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
INSERT INTO test_dataset
(first_name, last_name, geo_location)
select 
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
       (random() * (47.606209 - 25.427152)) + 25.427152 || ',' || (random() * (-124.389641 - -69.082237)) + -69.082237
FROM generate_series(1, 20);
```

United States Polygon

```
  POLYGON((-125.016047790785 48.208785494735764,-124.14089035719684 40.86877099667271,-121.5599275789894 36.06717734117032,-117.28671864846486 32.64978455562844,-113.72654637400285 32.31983439152819,-108.30080609779633 31.38368862238211,-105.8560247727104 31.460910518060302,-103.3967999601722 28.907930814307832,-101.79828909376985 29.931584620558965,-99.88202150341736 28.5312922037797,-97.23709470934983 25.954713168125338,-97.10002896107818 28.035767664456188,-94.14206168386124 29.48328979323645,-89.95286079259995 29.22199958232973,-88.80769857316915 30.441930703667964,-85.20950160725116 30.01610257057618,-83.55763826679038 29.988533620710356,-81.11550982715487 25.210558232017902,-79.82296508270082 26.439779557216667,-81.15323975356083 30.633102305542167,-80.61057729642516 32.67360737502075,-76.42226070031401 35.08303539533796,-76.74443890001484 38.7701053822278,-75.94326749398839 39.537424403566234,-75.85778562947489 37.61762713466268,-73.584262798466 41.05930212093591,-70.25489155819044 41.81899403776205,-70.84147400778302 43.17550270250865,-66.71653189743186 44.621194501738415,-67.98343208253185 47.27220127731093,-69.31075910289138 47.37130972398248,-70.71885174696367 45.18697869058366,-75.17835218911763 44.78963172176475,-77.22343210634047 43.57594231004268,-78.78804499198748 43.38258742737503,-82.22588977068015 41.561458542619334,-83.6165912767997 41.73128368552776,-83.54290001428807 45.0297037216441,-85.31768038061823 45.46571539393534,-86.68244256233366 41.733923340223015,-87.68199084704145 42.03741658905679,-87.39606874849632 45.11317999488102,-90.68977341771625 46.446847850725874,-92.2888738142187 46.476695535973505,-90.4321487639756 48.14018316715507,-96.18714160108408 48.89984262583636,-122.89609755085033 48.93083650796555,-125.016047790785 48.208785494735764))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of [`ST_GeneratePoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeneratePoints.html), which will return random points within a given geometry. Then you would have to transform the multipoints to several single points, and at last to generate the related fields

```sql
select 
      substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 7),
      substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
     (st_dump(ST_GeneratePoints('POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))',20))).geom;
```

Comment: I get an error `ERROR: function st_generatepoints(unknown, integer) does not exist`

Comment: @Steve it was introduced in v2.3  Which version are you using? Else try to cast the text to geometry first (it should be done automatically though)

Comment: I had to create the extension. Also, this doesn't seem to generate points within the polygon. The output is something like 0101000000176BFF5C36FF5AC00072E6DD0E824340 right now

Comment: @Steve yes, that's a geometry that you can insert into your column. If you want a human readable version of it, use `st_asText()` around it